# Using Wireless on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wifi, usb

I've got EDIMAX EW-7318USg - USB network adapter, it works fine in Windows 7 but somehow i couldn't get it to work on my Windows Server 2008 R2 ?

Has anyone tried to use Wireless LAN in Server 2008 R2 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since servers don't usually need wireless, it's disabled by default. however you can still do it by going to "Server Manager" -> "Features" and installing "Wireless LAN Service". i have personally tried it on an asus netbook (think: mobile DC replica) and i don't remember any problems to get it work.

if windows 7 got it's drivers, server should too. just install the feature and there you are. if not, insert the step, where you install drivers.

Comment: ok, let me find the driver first then.